# javascript on change not working on mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I have the following which works perfectly in a browser but the onchange element fails to fire on Android, and maybe other, devices. I have searched for a solution to this but my understanding of javascript is not so good, as you may be about to tell me.

HTML:

```
 <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 search-panel search">
   <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 search-panel"> 

     <form method="POST" action="/">

        <select class="form-control home_cat_id" name="home_cat_id">
            <option value='0'>Select Sales or Rentals</option>
            <option value='12'>Sales</option>
            <option value='1'>Rentals</option>
            <option value='4'>Rentals2</option>
        </select>

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

     //Reset dropdown on page load  
       $('.home_cat_id').val(0);

    // Check if value has changed //
       $(".home_cat_id").on("change", function(){


    // Pass the form values to the homepage_search.html file    
        $.post('/includes/homepage_search.html', $("select[name='home_cat_id']").serialize(), function(ret){

    // Detect if values have been passed back   
      if(ret!=""){

        $('.search').html(ret);
          } else {
               alert('ERROR');
              }

           });

    // Stop the page refreshing
      return false;

        }); 
     });
```

Thanks in advance for any advice given

Comment: try giving id to select

Answer (score 1):

Give the dropdown an id and use that id to select the element in you jQuery. Also, if you cache the select element, you get a small performance boost.

**HTML**

```
<div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 search-panel search"></div>
<div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 search-panel"></div>
<form method="POST" action="/">
  <select id="home_cat_id" class="form-control home_cat_id" name="home_cat_id">
    <option value='0'>Select Sales or Rentals</option>
    <option value='12'>Sales</option>
    <option value='1'>Rentals</option>
    <option value='4'>Rentals2</option>
  </select> 
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  // Cache the select element for performance
  $home_cat_id = $('#home_cat_id');    

  //Reset dropdown on page load  
  $home_cat_id.val(0);

  // Check if value has changed //
  $home_cat_id.on("change", function(){

    // Pass the form values to the homepage_search.html file    
    $.post(
      '/includes/homepage_search.html', 
      $home_cat_id.serialize(), 
      function(ret){

        // Detect if values have been passed back   
        if(ret!=""){
          $('.search').html(ret);
        } else {
          alert('ERROR');
        }
      });

    // Stop the page refreshing
    return false;

  }); 
});
```

Comment: Johan your addition has made no difference. The dropdown itself works but nothing is returned to the page on the Android Tab I am using.

Comment: @GalaxyTramp you problem was that "the onchange element fails to fire on Android". To understand why nothing is returned to the page, I need to see more of your code. What is returned from the call to homepage_search.html? Are the .search element refered to correctly?

Comment: There is not much more to it at the moment. These two divs above the form <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 search-panel search">
        <div class=" col-md-3 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 search-panel">  and it simply returns <p>FOO</p>

Comment: @GalaxyTramp please see my updated answer. I've added the closing div tag for both divs, but nothing else. I've tested this code and it do display FOO when changing the selected item. Please make sure your homepage_search.html page is in the correct place

Comment: I have updated my original code to show the position of the Div tags. Did you run this on an Android device to get a positive result? homepage_search is in the right place, this functions correctly on a web browser remember!

Comment: @GalaxyTramp I've tested it on a Samsung Galaxy II, and it works like a charm